# SQL select all fields from one table along with the sum of all values from another table matching a given condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: `customers` and `orders`.

Both `id` and `email` are unique in `customers` whereas `uid` and `price` can have duplicates in `orders`.

I want to select all fields from `customers` where email = 'john@doe.com', along with the total price this user paid from `orders`. If john doe didn't order anything yet (i.e. there is 0 record in `orders` where `uid` matches user `id`), I still need to return the fields list for this user, but the sum of the prices paid must be zero.

Here is what I tried:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.email, 
       t2.uid, (SELECT SUM(t2.price)) AS total_price
FROM customers t1, orders t2
WHERE t1.email = '$email' AND t2.uid = t1.id
```

Problem is this query only works if there is at least one record in `orders` because the check for `t2.uid = t1.id` is in the `where` clause.

If there is no records in `orders` having the same uid as the customer id, the query will return NULL, which is not what I want.

How can I **always** return all fields from `customers` along with the sum of all prices paid in `orders` even if there is no records in `orders` matching `customers.id` ?

Here is an example showing the desired output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I simple method is a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT c.*,
       (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(o.price), 0)
        FROM orders o
        WHERE o.u_id = c.id
       ) AS total_price
FROM customers c
WHERE c.email = '$email';
```

Hints for writing better queries:

- Learn to use parameters instead of munging query strings with parameter values.  Your `WHERE` should be more like `WHERE c.email = ?`.
- Your table aliases should be abbreviations for table names.
- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.
- When your data has no orders for a customer, it returns an empty set with no rows.  That is different from `NULL`, which means an indeterminate value.

Comment: Thank you Gordon Linoff for your solution and your valuable hints. Regarding your solution, what would be the proper way to add more parameters to your query ? for example retrieve the sum of all discounts from orders ?

Comment: @Hal_9100 . . . You should ask new questions as *questions*, with sample data, desired results, and so on.